# PostgreSQL: Run EXPLAIN on all queries in pg_stat_activity

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pg-stat-activity

I am investigating high load on a PostgreSQL database on RDS. As a part of the investigation, I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT now()-query_start, state, query FROM pg_stat_activity ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

This query returns the longest-running queries on the database. Then, I manually copy the query text to another window, and run `EXPLAIN` on each query to identify longer queries that need indexing.

Is there a way to automatically run `EXPLAIN` on each query in `pg_stat_activity`?

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly what you are looking for, but the auto_explain extension may be as close as you can get.  See [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html)